# In perl, is there a way to conditionally set an nv pair in a hash?

Tags: perl, cgi

I would like to conditionally set a hash key/value. I have done some searches but can't seem to find the right terms for my query. thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

my $q = new CGI;

my $foo = $q->cookie('Foo');
my $uri = 'https://www.google.com';

#is there a way to do this more elegantly?
print $q->redirect(-uri => $uri, -cookie => $foo) if ($foo);
print $q->redirect($uri) unless ($foo);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print $q->redirect(
  $foo ? (-uri => $uri, -cookie => $foo) 
       : $uri
);
```

Comment: i didn't realize i could do this conditional logic within the argument 'area'. pretty neat, but seems obvious now. haha

Answer (score 4):

at minimum, I'd use the [conditional operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator)

```
print $foo 
     ? $q->redirect(-uri => $uri, -cookie => $foo) 
     : $q->redirect($uri);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use PerlX::Maybe;

print $q->redirect( -uri => $uri, maybe -cookie => $foo );
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI, your `$uri` could have always been specified using the `-uri` argument.

There's always the [Enterprise](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsecret#Enterprise) "operator" if you want to obviate the need for `PerlX::Maybe` (and make your code hard to read):

```
print $q->redirect(
      -uri    => $uri,
    ( -cookie => $foo )x!! $foo,
);
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. It's annoying that it's a secret. I've already implemented the the conditional solution, but appreciate that you took the time to link me to this.